# Virtual desktop screen resolution much larger than actual screen resolution which only shows a portion of it and lets you pan around

Tags: windows, window-manager

A few years back I had a setup which came with a driver or some software so that you could virtually increase your desktop resolution to enormous resolutions like 6000x6000. But since the actual maximum screen resolution of the monitor was only something like 1280x800, it only showed a portion of it. It let you pan around when you took your mouse pointer to the corners and edges. Something like this:

[image]

Is there a software that lets you do this?

OS: Windows. License: Any

Comment: I think the Magnifier that comes with Windows already has a full screen mode that does that. I haven't tried it with Windows 8 yet. However: `Full-screen mode and lens mode are only available as part of the Aero experience`([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-items-bigger-magnifier#1TC=windows-7))

Comment: @Timmy I'm afraid you've missed the main point. I want the screen resolution to be increased to something like  6000x3000 px. Then, yeah I guess Magnifier would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found **GiMeSpace.com** sells a product that will do it in 1 or 2 dimensions, with a trial version available.

Comment: Would you mind giving pricing information, and explain more about the dimensions and UI (I think they use the mouse in a certain way, for instance. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Can't believe something like this existed for so long. Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1):

On earlier versions of Windows, the Matrox cards such as the Millenium included this feature in their driver. It was certainly not a bug in the driver @CalvT. The driver was coded so that when you reached the edge of the physical screen, the driver panned the virtual desktop across the physical screen. On the Matrox cards, this was known as 'Virtual Desktop'. Here is a link or two that references the feature...

https://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/pdf/support/manuals/en_inst.pdf

This link is for the Mac driver, but explains the feature better than the PDF above...

https://www.matrox.com/graphics/media/pdf/support/manuals/en_mac2.pdf

I'm afraid I don't know how to configure this for later Windows versions either. However, I too am searching for it, since I think that combined with a set of VR glasses, having the pan feature triggered when you move your head from left to right could be a very natural way to pan around a desktop that is wider than your display device.

Answer (score -1):

Presuming your graphics card can support higher resolutions than your monitor can support you can increase the desktop size.

Go to Display Settings. Then click on Advanced Settings. Under Monitor uncheck Hide modes that this monitor Cannot Display or Under Adapter Click on list all modes

Then simply choose one larger than your monitor supports and give it a go.
However be warned some monitors will simply display a message saying input is out of range.

I don't think there would be any software for this, as it is the drivers that define it. It could be your old computer had a driver that wasn't coded properly.

Comment: I have never seen a monitor that pans around if you set a resolution higher than it can support.

Comment: I didn't see the reply to this!! :/ I had one of those EEE laptops, and depending on what resolution you chose, sometimes you could pan up and down, because the height set was more than the "relative" height of the screen.